# Create MongoDB document that has a list of documents in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to create a MongoDB document in Java to insert into my MongoDB collection. Currently, the MongoDB document I am using has no list of documents in it and I want to add one to it.

My document should look something like this:

```
{
 id : 1,
 events : [
           { event_id : 1, processed : false},
           { event_id : 2, processed : false},
           .
           .
          ],
 assigned_user : 32
}
```

To create the MongoDB document, I am forced to create a

```
Map<String, Object> dataFields
```

And then transform it to a MongoDB document.

So to add the list of Documents I need, I thought of creating

```
 List<Document> events
```

Then creating a document for each event I need, and then add it to the list of `events`.

Finally, I would simply add the list `events` to the map `dataFields`, and then create the final MongoDB document.

Would this work? If not, what is the flaw? Logic or implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an idea, try it. And if your project environment does not allow you to try, sandbox it. I'll give it a go, but my Java is rusty, and I don’t have the JDK on this computer. Start with this:

```
public class MongoSandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        // Connect to the local test db
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());

        // Get a test collection
        MongoCollection<Document> docs = db.getCollection("docs");

        // Create a dummy list of events
        List<Document> events = new ArrayList<Document>();
        events.add(new Document("random", "data"));
        events.add(new Document("random", "data2"));
        events.add(new Document("random", "data3"));

        // Create your main document
        Document mainDoc = new Document("events", events);
        docs.insert(mainDoc);

        client.close();
    }
}
```